# Laravel - dá pra fazer apenas o backend primeiro?

Tags: laravel, front-end, back-end

Estou aprendendo laravel e já consigo fazer algumas coisinhas (trabalhar com as rotas, migrations, eloquent, controllers, etc).

Porém, fico batendo cabeça com o front, pois não sei a melhor forma de se trabalhar com isso nesse framework, daí perco muito tempo fritando meu cérebro com isso e acabo não desenvolvendo de fato o que eu quero, então gostaria de saber se eu posso fazer todo o backend primeiramente e aí sim ir pro font?

Comment: Claro, se souberes o que o front-end vai conter/precisar do servidor

Comment: Claro, que não. Não tem como você testar rotas sem o front end

Comment: Claro, você pode criar os templates estáticos e depois utlilizar o blade para por dinâmica após o back pronto. Alías eu adoro usar componentes front end do vue js.

Comment: Como pode ver, essa pergunta é bem ampla e baseada em opiniões =)

Comment: Sim, da para criar os layout e depois só integrar, mas  assim as vezes é preferivel ter um backend funcional e depois implementar o  front-end é menos trabalhoso mas quem  decide a ordem é você

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sim**, é possível.

Você pode aplicar a abordagem conhecida como "*API First*", onde você começa **planejando** a API (*Application Programming Interface*) **antes de qualquer desenvolvimento**, tanto *back end*, quanto *front end*.

Com o desenho da sua aplicação (fluxo de entradas e saídas) é possível disparar ambos os desenvolvimentos (*back end* e *front end*) simultaneamente, com outra pessoa, por exemplo.

Referência: [Three Principles of API First Design](https://medium.com/adobe-io/three-principles-of-api-first-design-fa6666d9f694)